# Trying to Get SSL Up with Docker Nginx and Certbot

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have hit this roadblock where I am not able get the SSL Certificates from Let's encrypt.
I am using Nginx , Certbot and trying to get SSL running for my site with a node backend.

I tried to follow this post as my knowledge is limited. Any help pointers would be highly appreciated.

https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

As the post mentions , I first try to run the script to get a dummy certificate. I have modified the script to point to my domain.
But I get this error

> Failed authorization procedure. example.org (http-01):
>   urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect
>   to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching
>   http://example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/Jca_rbXSDHEmXz8-y3bKKckD8g0lsuoQJgAxeSEz5Jo:
>   Connection refused
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: example.org    Type:   connection    Detail: Fetching
>   http://example.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/Jca_rbXSDHEmXz8-y3bKKckD8g0lsuoQJgAxeSEz5Jo:
>   Connection refused

This is my nginx configuration

```
   upstream app {
         server app:3000;
     }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.org;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app/;
        }
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
        # location /api/ {
        #     proxy_pass         http://app/;
        #     proxy_redirect     off;
        #     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        #     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        # }
    }

    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.org; #for demo purposes
    }
    }
```

Comment: while creating let's encrypt certificate , did you get a chance to upload the file at the desired location to prove that you are owner of the domain

Comment: Have you replaced everywhere domain "example.org" with your domain name?

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.
Was easier to setup and got my server up with SSL using the Proxy Companion.